# p:dashboard widgets state

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dashboard

I have dashboard and 3 widgets added to it.

```
<ui:define name="mainContent">
            <h:form id="dashboard" styleClass="main-page-dashboard">
                <p:dashboard id="board" model="#{serviceDashboardController.model}">
                    <p:ajax event="reorder"
                        listener="#{serviceDashboardController.handleReorder}" />

                    <p:panel id="calendar" header="#{msg.day_agenda}"
                        styleClass="calendar-dashboard dashboard-inner">
                        <ui:insert name="registry">
                            <ui:include src="/html/services/day_agenda_dashboard.xhtml" />
                        </ui:insert>
                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panel id="notary_tasks" header="#{msg.tasks}" styleClass="task-dashboard dashboard-inner">
                        <ui:insert name="notary_registry">
                            <ui:include src="/html/services/inboxMessages.xhtml" />
                        </ui:insert>
                        <p:link outcome="/html/services/inbox"
                            value="#{msg.more_not_tasks}" styleClass="enot-more-link" />
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:panel id="registry" header="#{msg.notary_registry}"
                        styleClass="registry-dashboard dashboard-inner">
                        <ui:insert name="registry">
                            <ui:include src="/html/services/notary_registry_dashboard.xhtml" />
                        </ui:insert>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:dashboard>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
```

So.. User can reorder all 3 widgets.

What I need to do is, to save the state(position) of reordered widgets.

Now I know how to check the possition of every widget by  `event.getWidgetId()`,`event.getColumnIndex()` but I am looking for all dashboard arrangement, if there is something like that.

So after user reorder it, I could save it, so user after reconnecting would see dashboard as he left before, not by default set-up.

**EDIT**: just now thought that all columns we add widgets to, is added to model.

```
model.addColumn(column1);
        model.addColumn(column2);
        model.addColumn(column3);

        column1.addWidget("calendar");
        column1.addWidget("notary_tasks");
        column1.addWidget("notary_registry");
```

So I imagine, I should dig deeper into `model`..
So if anyone has more ideas, feel free to.. :)

tomcat 7, Primefaces 5.1, Mojarra 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer was kinda easy, just needed to read some documentation ofcourse. ! :)

So, state of the dasboard can be saved with JSF method `getColumns();`

```
List<DashboardColumn> dashboardList = model.getColumns();
```

And then all you need is to pick format you saving it, for my example it's `Json` beeing saved on alfresco Share.

```
public String getModelWidgets() {
        List<DashboardColumn> dashboardList = model.getColumns();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String toJson = gson.toJson(dashboardList);

        return toJson;
    }
```